# iphone: creating the 'blue bubble contacts' effect in ComposeEmail?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tags, core-animation

I want to create an effect similar to the 'blue bubble tag' effect in the Compose Email Page where the recipients email address appears.

I need to design a similar effect to allow users to create 'tags' for a picture.. Do I have to use Core Animation for this? Can someone please give me some pointers on where / what i need to use?

Comment: You don't need Core Animation since it's not animating...

Comment: On OS X, this functionality is provided by `NSTokenField`. I know that doesn't help you directly, but it may help you in future Googling.

Answer (score 0):

[Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) has something that is like this.  You can mine it for code.  What you are looking for is in the [TTMessageController](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTMessageController.h)